# Delete specific item from cookie by id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

This is the first time I am using cookie in laravel. I am adding products to wish list by cookie as an array like this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "product_name" => Book
    "product_image" => "kim.jpg-74128.jpg"
    "product_price" => 2332
    "product_id" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "product_name" => Gun
    "product_image" => "Screenshot from 2020-11-12 10-29-53.png-88799.png"
    "product_price" => 334
    "product_id" => 2
  ]
]
```

The code below  deletes all products from cookie but I want to  delete them by id  but could not find to remove them by this way from cookie directly

```
Cookie::forget('myCookie')
```

Answer (score 0):

`myCookie` is the cookie key. You would need to give each product its own cookie. Personally, I would suggest using another method to persist a product to a wish list.